# karatelabs provided example https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/examples/gatling does not run

Tags: karate

Here's karate provided  [example code](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/examples/gatling)

Here's how I repeat the issue

```
./gradlew gatlingRun


08:01:53.234 [main] ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User defined Simulation class mock.CatsKarateSimulation could not be loaded
```

Could someone please tell me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: search for other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+gatling+gradle